# PySpark: How to Handle Inconsisten JSON Data Types for a Field

Tags: json, pyspark, databricks, jsonschema

I have a large JSON string stored in a column in a delta table. I am using structured streaming for reads and writes. I have a pesky nested field 'value' which comes through in two types: string, number, and sometimes null. Because it is sometimes a string and sometimes a number, I have been unable to find a way to handle and parse it without one or the other becoming a null value. Example:

| json_col |
| --- |
| `{"value": "123"}` |
| `{"value": 456}` |
| `{"value": null}` |

If I specify the schema as this:

```
    schema = StructType([StructField('value', StringType())])
```

The strings are parsed but the numbers are not converted, they just become more null values. In the scenario above, row two would just have value as null.
The reverse happens if I specify the schema as LongType; the strings in the raw data become null. Is there a way to efficiently handle this without some row-by-row payload modification? I checked the docs for the json stream reader and looked for a function but did not see any prebuilt ways for handling this. Wondering if I am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

In pyspark version 3.5.0, I don't find numbers getting nulled when I specify `StringType()` both in batch and streaming versions.

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import sys
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, max, greatest

sc = SparkContext('local')
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)


inputFile = "../data/unionDataTypeDir"
schema_provided = StructType([StructField("value", StringType(), nullable=True)])

initialDF = sqlContext.read.schema(schema_provided).json(inputFile)

print("pyspark version :", sc.version)

print("Normal batch dataframe")
initialDF.show(n=100, truncate=False)

streaming_df = sqlContext.readStream \
    .schema(schema_provided) \
    .json(inputFile)

print("Streaming dataframe")
query = streaming_df.writeStream \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .format("console") \
    .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

Output :

```
pyspark version : 3.5.0
Normal batch dataframe
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|123  |
|456  |
|NULL |
+-----+

Streaming dataframe
-------------------------------------------
Batch: 0
-------------------------------------------
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|  123|
|  456|
| NULL|
+-----+
```

Comment: Perhaps being on 3.4.1 was my issue or maybe I just missed something. Retrying the load on 3.5.0 now

Comment: @Cole1998 : did upgrading the pyspark version resolved the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately no. For the payloads where it comes as a number, it is still null @user238607

Comment: @Cole1998 : Not sure what is going on because we simulated the streaming dataframe as well.